# Fetch a text file stored in mysql table using python

Tags: php, python, mysql

In my project, I have a database named "uploadedfile" database to store a "demo.txt" file to a mysql table "file" inside my database in mysql. Now I want to use that .txt file in my python file to convert it to .xml file.

My question is :

How to fetch that .txt file from mysql database table in file format?

After converting it to .xml file how to upload that file into "xml" table in same "uploadedfile" database so that PHP can retreive it for downloading.

```
Please suggest if there is any way to proceed or is there any alternative way to do this. Please.

My SQL queries explaining the details of my schema are:

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| uploadedfile       |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> USE uploadedfile;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_uploadedfile |
+------------------------+
| file                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE file;
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default      | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL         | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | Untitled.txt |                |
| mime    | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | text/plain   |                |
| size    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0            |                |
| data    | mediumblob          | NO   |     | NULL         |                |
| created | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL         |                |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM file where name="fourth.txt";
+----+------------+------------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | name       | mime       | size | data | created             |
+----+------------+------------+------+------+---------------------+
|  3 | fourth.txt | text/plain | 8785 |      | 2016-05-13 10:47:29 |
+----+------------+------------+------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

I need this fourth.txt to get converted to .xml using my python script.
But I am stuck as how to fetch that file from mySQL database.

Please help
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it using relative path of that file like

```
'folder_name/' + 'file name from DB'
```

you can also use absolute path to your file but generally it is considered best practice to use relative path, so that your website will not be bound to that base path of where it is currently deployed. For example, it will be able to worrk on localhost, as well as on your public domain, without modification

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying now

Comment: What is this 'folder_name/'... Where is it in my case inside my db of mysql?

Comment: It is the folder name which contain your fourth.txt file

Comment: If your code file and fourth.txt file are in same directory, then you don't need to write folder_name.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you, because the "fourth.txt" is a text file inside a table called "file" inside my own database called "uploadedfile" in mysql server. I want tor retrieve "fourth.txt" from the mysql table called "file".

Comment: okay but where fourth.txt file is stored? somewhere in your directory?

Comment: In your DB fourth.txt is just a string which is the name of your file. That file must be stored somewhere, If its not then first create that file somewhere in your directory.

Comment: Yes once the user has chosen the file to upload, PHP curl submits the file to the PHP script running on a server. The file gets stored in temporary folder of my server where the PHP script lies and I am doing that using move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],/my required directory on server/) , after that the PHP file uploads it to the mysql DB.

Comment: The file is stored in a directory where the PHP code lies that sends the file to DB. So, should I pass on the file in URL from PHP and accept it inside python script using python REQUEST api?'

Comment: Okay then you need to concat your directory path with file name like  `/my required directory on server/ + 'filename from DB'` then you can convert that file to .xml then update new file name to DB.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for your suggestions. I was just going blank till now. I got it what you want to say...

Comment: Sorry, but that returns a string. But how to open and read the contents of the file??

Comment: I got it using :                                                                                   import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="#########",                        user="#########",         # your username                      passwd="##########",  # your password                      db="uploadedfile")        # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM file")
for row in cur.fetchall():
   result = row[1]with open("/temporary/directory/path" + result) as f: